# Does memory need to be allocated when reading input with getchar() in C?

Tags: c, memory, char, malloc, getchar

In the code below, should memory be allocated for the pointer `c` using a function such as `malloc()`? I'm worried that incrementing `c` may cause it to point to another variable and thus override it when `*c = getchar()` gets called.

```
char *c;
int count = 0;

while( (*c=getchar()) != '\n' ){
    c++;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a pointer. There should be “incompatible integer to pointer conversion” warnings.

Comment: Why are you changing the code?

Comment: Only change the code afterwards if you have made a typo or so. Do not change it to "correct" it after looking at the answers.

Comment: Yeah, you d need to copy the result of `getchar()` to some allocated memory. That doesn't necessarily mean using malloc, i.e. `char c = '\0'; char* p = &c; *p = getchar();`

Answer (score 1):

The code posted has problems:

- `c` is uninitialized, to writing to it has immediate undefined behavior, incrmenting it only makes it worse.
- you do not test for end of file, nor do you test for any array boundary, so even if `c` was made to point to an actual array, static, automatic or dynamically allocated from the heap with `malloc()`, you must check that `c` stays within the boundaries of that array.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[100];
    int c, count, limit;
    char *p;

    p = buf;                  /* p points to an automatic array, no malloc needed */
    count = 0;
    limit = sizeof(buf) - 1;  /* maximum number of characters to store */

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (count < limit)
           *p++ = c;
        count++;
    }
    if (count < limit)
        *p = '\0';
    else
        buf[limit] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is one with memory allocation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *buf, *p;
    int c, count, limit;

    limit = 99;
    p = buf = malloc(limit + 1);   /* p points to an array allocated from the heap */
    count = 0;

    if (buf == NULL) {
        printf("allocation failure\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (count < limit)
           *p++ = c;
        count++;
    }
    if (count < limit)
        *p = '\0';
    else
        buf[limit] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", buf);
    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')` is a classic C idiom to read a byte from standard input, and store it in an `int` variable `c`, check for end if file and check for end of line in a single control expression. `&&` evaluates its left hand side first and only evaluates its right hand side if the result, a boolean value `0` or `1` of type `int`, cannot be determined from the value of the left hand side. This peculiarity is called *shortcut evaluation* and applies to `||` and the ternary operator `?` / `:` too.
- `c` must have a type that can accommodate all values retuned by `getchar()`: all values of type `unsigned char` and the special negative value `EOF`. Neither `char` nor `signed char` nor `unsigned char` are appropriate for this, as `c == EOF` would either incorrectly match for `\377` (`'ÿ'` in ISO-8859-1) for the signed `char` case or never match for the unsigned `char` case. `int` is the correct type for `c`.

Comment: Could you give us a tiny bit more insight into how `((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')` is evaluated? Is it always guaranteed that `c=getchar()` is evaluated first before `c != '\n'` is tested?

Comment: @AndyJ: absolutely guaranteed. `&&` and `||` are specified to only evaluate their right hand side if the result cannot be determined from the value of the left hand side. Hence `c != `'\n'` will only be evaluated if `c != EOF`, but in this particular case, it does not matter as evaluating this test would still be valid.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it should.

But you don't really need a pointer here. [`getchar()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) returns an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation we can see that the prototype for `getchar` looks like this:

```
int getchar(void)
```

It does not return a pointer, so yes if you want to use a pointer the way you do you have to make sure it points at something. In fact, your code give this warning:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     while( (c=getchar()) != '\n' ){
              ^
```

You don't necessarily need to use `malloc` per se, but you have to make sure that `c` points at a valid address. And since you're incrementing `c` you are also responsible for making sure that those addresses are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, memory needs to be allocated.

And it's not just `getchar` -- *any* time you have a pointer like

```
char *c;
```

you have to be careful to think about where it points, and whether there's any allocated memory there.

And in fact, if all you say is

```
char *c;
```

you do *not* know where the pointer `c` points, so you have no idea whether there's any allocated memory there, but if we had to guess, we'd have to say there probably isn't.

Saying

```
char *c;
```

and then asking where the pointer `c` points is just about like saying

```
int i;
```

and then asking what

```
printf("%d\n", i);
```

will print.  Since we didn't set `i` to any value, we don't know what it will print.

If you want to read several characters, and store them in an array, and use a pointer to do that, you can -- but you need to allocate the array, and make the pointer point to it.  It might look something like this.  By the way, at this point I'm going to change the name of the pointer variable to `p`, which is a more usual name for a pointer.  (`c` sounds like a character, not a pointer to a character.)

```
char *p;
char arr[10];
int count = 0;
p = &arr[0];

while( (*p=getchar()) != '\n' ){
    p++;
    count++;
}
```

Now the pointer variable `p` has somewhere to point, so using it to store characters with `*p=getchar()` is valid.

Now, with that said, we've got two pretty big problems.  One is that the array is declared big enough to hold 10 characters, but the loop that fills the array does noting to check that.  If someone types 10 or more characters before hitting Enter or Return, `p` will sail off the end of the space that's allocated for the array, and start overwriting other memory, as you were worried about.

An then the second difficulty is that we're not checking for end-of-file.  Moreover, we *can't* properly check for end-of-file, because the end-of-file indicator `EOF` isn't a valid character value and so won't fit into `*p`, which can only hold character values.